# rails undefined method `reviewer' for #<Review

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I'm creating review to my posts, all works but i dont know how to show who wrote the review
i'm trying this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :reviewers, :class_name => 'Post', :foreign_key => 'reviewer_id'
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :reviews
  belongs_to :reviewers, class_name: 'User', :foreign_key => 'reviewer_id'
  default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end

class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @review = @post.reviews.new(post_id:params[:post_id])
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @review = @post.reviews.build(review_params)
        if @review.save
          flash[:success] = "Ваш отзыв добавлен"
          redirect_to post_path @post
        else
          render 'new'
        end
    end


    private

    def review_params
        params.require(:review).permit(:post_id, :body, :reviewer_id).merge(:reviewer_id => current_user.id)
    end
end
```

and my view

```
<% @post.reviews.each do |review| %>
  <p>
    <strong>reviewer:</strong>
    <%= review.reviewer.email %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>review:</strong>
    <%= review.body %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

my migration

```
class CreateReviews < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :reviews do |t|
      t.text :body
      t.references :post, index: true
      t.references :reviewer, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

but rails given error undefined method `reviewer' for #
Help please dsfsdf

Comment: I'm confused by the models. A user has many reviewers? Users get reviewed? Or do *posts* get reviewed? And does a post have a *single* reviewer, or *multiple* reviewers?

Comment: post get reviewed))) and i want to show who create the review

Comment: Then why does `User` include `has_many :reviewers`? Should that be `has_many :reviews`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you have a pluralization issue:

A post have many reviews by **many** reviewers (one for each review). But you are storing the foreign key within the post so you written the problematic line:

```
belongs_to :reviewers, class_name: 'User', :foreign_key => 'reviewer_id'
```

The issue here is that it is a singular association with a plural name.

I think that you are trying to say here that a

```
class Post
  have_many :reviewers, class_name: 'User', through: :reviews
end
```

But as you are trying to access the reviewers from the review what you really need is to add:

```
class Review
  belongs_to :reviewer, class_name: 'User'
end
```

Then you can access the reviewers from the review as expected:

```
<% @post.reviews.each do |review| %>
  <p>
    <strong>reviewer:</strong>
    <%= review.reviewer.email %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>review:</strong>
    <%= review.body %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

There is also an error in User:

```
has_many :reviewers, :class_name => 'Post', :foreign_key => 'reviewer_id'
```

As it should be:

```
has_many :reviews, :foreign_key => 'reviewer_id'
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but now when i try <%= review.reviewer.email %> rails given error undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass but if i try this <%= review.reviewer %> in chrome rails show this:reviewer: #<User:0x3cad2f8>

Comment: what does <%= review.reviewer.name %> yield?

Comment: @Adyl You have some review without a Reviewer (you should add a validation for that if this is required). You can use something like `<%= review.reviewer.try(:email) || 'Missing reviewer' %>` to find the error. (there may be better alternatives)

Comment: thanks a lot but all trouble in this: <% @user.posts.includes(:reviews).each do |post| %>
  <% post.reviews.each do |review| %>
     <%= link_to post.name, post %>
     <br/>
     <%= review.user.name %>
     <%= review.body %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using `.user`. Check the `belongs_to` in your model.

```
Review.first.user
```

Comment: Thanks, add to the view     <%= review.user.name %> rails given error undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0):

As a previous poster pointed out, your user association for Review is :user, so your view should probably look like this:

```
<% @post.reviews.each do |review| %>
  <p>
    <strong>reviewer:</strong>
    <%= review.user.name unless review.user.nil? %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>review:</strong>
    <%= review.body %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: hanks, add to the view <%= review.user.name %> rails given error undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Well, you'll need to make sure the review has a user associated with it first.  I'll update my example with a simple check.

Comment: Sorry, I would need more information about your models then.  I agree with Dave Newton, it's a bit confusing.  Have you played around with the records in question using IRB?

Comment: no i doesnt play with records, user create review to the post, and i want show who create this review, post must be have only one review, sorry for my bad english and in rails im noob

Comment: Use "rails c" to enter IRB mode.  You can then test model associations as much as you want.